# Increase by 10% each time

Tags: php

I have a game, and in that game you have a "House" that you upgrade. To me and you, that house is nothing more than a number in a database. Now, to upgrade the house, you need resources (more numbers in databases) and I want the cost to increase, each time the house increases.

So for example

- My house is level 1, it costs 100 to upgrade to level 2
- I spend the 100 to level up my house but the price increases by 10%
- So house is level 2, it costs 110 to upgrade to level 3

etc..This looks very simple, I don't know how I'm struggling with this, here's how I've got so far..

```
$goldcostperhouse = 100;
$goldcostperhouse2 = 100 + $goldcostperhouse / 10;
$woodcostperhouse = 100;
$woodcostperhouse2 = 100 + $woodcostperhouse / 10;
$upgradecostgold = $house * $goldcostperhouse;
$upgradecostwood = $house * $woodcostperhouse2;
```

The cost stays at 100 every time with that :(

Here's the full code

```
<?php
include ("header.php");
include ("connect.php");

$stats_get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stats.gold, stats.wood, stats.id FROM stats WHERE stats.id =     $id4");
$stats_got = mysqli_fetch_array($stats_get);
$gold10 = $stats_got['gold'];
$wood10 = $stats_got['wood'];

$buildings_get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT buildings.house, buildings.id FROM buildings WHERE     buildings.id = $id4");
$gotbuildings = mysqli_fetch_array($buildings_get);
$house = $gotbuildings['house'];
$nextlevel = $house + 1;
$goldcostperhouse = 200;
$goldcostperhouse2 = 200 + $goldcostperhouse / 10;
$woodcostperhouse = 200;
$woodcostperhouse2 = 200 + $woodcostperhouse / 10;
$upgradecostgold = $house * $goldcostperhouse;
$upgradecostwood = $house * $woodcostperhouse2;



IF ($house <= 0){
echo "You need to buy a house, it costs 76,000 Wood and 24,000 Gold!<br>";
    IF(isset($_POST['buy'])){
    echo "You have bought the house!";
    IF($gold10 < 24000){
        echo "You don't have enough Gold!";
    }elseif($wood10 < 76000){
        echo "You don't have enough Wood!";
    }else{
    $removegold = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold - 24000 WHERE stats.id = $id4");
    $removewood = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.wood = stats.wood - 76000 WHERE stats.id = $id4");
    $givehouse = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE buildings SET buildings.house = 1 WHERE buildings.id = $id4");
    }
}

?>
<html>
<body>

<form action="house.php" method="post">
<input type="Submit" name="buy" value="Buy"/>
</form>

<?php

}else{

echo "House level: ",number_format($house),"<br>";
echo "It will cost ",number_format($upgradecostgold)," Gold and ",number_format($upgradecostwood), " Wood to upgrade your house to level ",number_format($nextlevel),"<br>";

IF(isset($_POST['upgrade'])){
IF($gold10 < $upgradecostgold){
    echo "You do not have enough Gold!";
    }elseif($wood10 < $upgradecostwood){
    echo "You do not have enough Wood!";
    }else{
    echo "You have upgraded your house!<br>";
    $removegold = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.gold = stats.gold - $upgradecostgold WHERE stats.id = $id4");
    $removewood = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.wood = stats.wood - $upgradecostwood WHERE stats.id = $id4");
    $givehouse = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE buildings SET buildings.house = buildings.house + 1     WHERE buildings.id = $id4");
    }

}

?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="house.php" method="post">
<input type="Submit" name="upgrade" value="Upgrade"/>
</form>

<?php

}

include("footer.php")
?>
```

Comment: Firstly, use prepared statements. Secondly, have you out put the result of the query to see what is being output?

Comment: math simplification: `$x = $x + ($x / 10)` could just as well be `$x = $x * 1.1`. and then for the level: `$x *= pow(1.1, $level)`

Comment: @LiamSorsby I keep forgetting to start using them! Force of habit lol

Comment: @MarcB it only does it once, so it will go from 200 to 220, but it will stay at 220, even if I upgrade it again

Comment: @RyanMckenna you seem to just use a figure from what I can see and not use the new house "Value"

Comment: yes, but ugprade #3 -> `100 * (1.1 ^ 3) -> $133.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at how you're calculating the house cost:

```
Level 1 = 100
Level 2 = 100 * 1.1
Level 3 = 100 * 1.1 * 1.1
Level 4 = 100 * 1.1 * 1.1 * 1.1
etc.
```

This can be represented with the formula (where `^` is "to the power of"):

```
cost = 100 * (1.1 ^ (level - 1))
```

You can then express the upgrade cost in PHP as a function of the house level, using `pow` to calculate the mathematical power:

```
function upgradeCost($houseLevel) {
    return intval(100 * pow(1.1, $houseLevel - 1));
}
```

Or you can just perform it inline in your code:

```
$upgradeCost = intval(100 * pow(1.1, $houseLevel - 1));
```

This will give you the sequence 100, 110, 121, 133, 146, 161, 177, 194, 214, 235...

Note that I've used `intval` to make sure the cost is an integer. If you can have non-integer costs, you can remove the `intval`.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you to explain it a bit? Better than me copy/pasting it in :) (specifically the "pow" and "function" as I've never used either)

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer with some explanation. As for functions, have a look at http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpfunctions.php.